# Erro ao cancelar uma tarefa de exportação de imagem no EC2

Tags: amazon-aws

Criei uma uma tarefa para exportação de imagem e algum tempo após não sendo mais necessário quis exportar quis cancelar mas ocorre um erro.

Este comando:
aws ec2 cancel-export-task --export-task-id export-i-fgwr77c4

Retorna este erro:
A client error (IncorrectState) occurred when calling the CancelExportTask operation: Task can not be cancelled at this stage: 'export-i-fgwr77c4'

Este comando:
aws ec2 describe-export-tasks
Retorna o seguinte:
{
    "ExportTasks": [
        {
            "State": "active",
            "ExportTaskId": "export-i-fgwr77c4",
            "InstanceExportDetails": {
                "InstanceId": "i-07d3c3c3c4c43b5a4",
                "TargetEnvironment": "vmware"
            },
            "ExportToS3Task": {
                "DiskImageFormat": "vmdk",
                "S3Key": "exportexport-i-fgwr77c4.ova",
                "ContainerFormat": "ova",
                "S3Bucket": "agtis"
            }
        }
  ]
}